# Why can't I use the print() or println() method in java.io.PrintStream as it is after importing the class?

Tags: java

Apologies for this silly question, but while I was learning java classes, I tried the following

```
javap -c java.lang.System | grep -i out
  public static final java.io.PrintStream out;

javap java.io.PrintStream | grep print
public void print(boolean);
public void print(char);
public void print(int);
public void print(long);
public void print(float);
public void print(double);
public void print(char[]);
public void print(java.lang.String);
public void print(java.lang.Object);
public void println();
public void println(boolean);
public void println(char);
public void println(int);
public void println(long);
public void println(float);
public void println(double);
public void println(char[]);
public void println(java.lang.String);
public void println(java.lang.Object);
public java.io.PrintStream printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
public java.io.PrintStream printf(java.util.Locale, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
```

And I tried to see if I can import `java.io.PrintStream` and use `print()` or `println()` as it is, instead of `System.out.println()`.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
println('a');
```

And it came out with a compile error saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method print(char) is undefined for the type array
    at array.main(array.java:16)
```

Why can't I use `println()` as it is after importing `java.io.Printstream` ?

Comment: Because you need a `PrintStream` object to call it on.

Comment: The closest you can get is `import static System.out;`, which allows you to do `out.println()`. That only saves 7 characters though, and given that most IDEs have an autocomplete feature that works on `sysout`, it's hardly worth doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `println` is an instance method of the `PrintStream` class, and you need an instance of a class to call instance methods.

However, `System.out` is an instance of `PrintStream`, so you can do:

```
 System.out.println("blah blah")
```

or you can create a new `PrintStream` instance, for example to write to a file:

```
 PrintStream p = new PrintStream(filename);
 p.println("blah blah");
```

This section in the Java Tutorial can be helpful: [Lesson: Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the tutorials as well. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of PrintStream because println is not static.

You can try this:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(System.out);
// or better
PrintStream printStream = System.out;
printStream.println('a');
```

PrintStream needs a OutputStream for the constructor, you can give the OutputStream you want:

ByteArrayOutputStream, 
FileOutputStream, 
FilterOutputStream, 
ObjectOutputStream, 
OutputStream, 
PipedOutputStream

Javadoc :
[OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html)
[PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Comment: `System.out` is already a `PrintStream`. Why create a second `PrintStream` to wrap it ?

Comment: You're right. It was the easiest way to create a PrintStream and use his println with the same effect as Sysout. PO said : "use print() or println() as it is, instead of System.out.println(). " PrintStream printStream = System.out; is also a solution (nicer btw).

Answer (score 0):

In Java You always need to call a method (function) on a specific object.
That's why if you want to call any of these methods (print, println) you need to create the object of type java.io.PrintStream first.

For example, try the following code:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
...
PrintStream ps = System.out;
ps.print('a');
```

It creates the PrintStream object which prints to the cosole and prints the given char argument there.

Comment: It should be `PrintStream ps = System.out`

Comment: Yes I know. Just wanted to do it this way to show the author why his code didn't work (for educational purposes). Cause the question was not really about streams but rather objects creation process and the way methods can be called.

Comment: But isn't it misleading to tell the OP to create an additional instance when he doesn't need one ?

Comment: Ok, you are right that this is better way. But looking at the type of questions asked and the comment about just learning Java I considered that it was important to show the process of creating the object explicitly for educational purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to instantiate PrintStream class but it doesn't have a default no-arg constructor.
So it's an easy way to use its static instance from System class and call the print() method directly.